# Ошибка "Сервис заблокирован" для "JavaScript API и HTTP Геокодер" Яндекс.Карт, хотя бесплатным ключом еще ни разу не воспользовались

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Во получения бесплатного API ключа на одном из этапов на странице появилась надпись, что возникла какая-то ошибка и предложение перезагрузить страницу. Я перезагрузил. После этого в списке "Ключи API" появилась надпись "Key #1" и пустой ключ (я же не прошел до конца всю процедуру получения). После повторной попытки получения бесплатного ключа этот "Key #2" появился в списке ключей, но одновременно с этим на странице "API интерфейсы" появилась надпись "Сервис заблокирован". В итоге я еще ни разу не пользовался ключом, а меня уже заблокировали. Что мне делать в этой ситуации, как разблокировать сервис?

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что адресовать его следует в соответствующую техподдержку

Comment: так же - все работало - и перестало

Comment: И как разобрались? у меня такая же беда